# jQuery's selective modules for signalR?

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, webpack, signalr

I've installed the latest version of jQuery using `npm install jQuery --save`.

[This operation created modules folders in the `node_modules` folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MK9l.jpg)

Since signalr (client side) relies on jQuery - I was able to do this :

```
var jQuery = require('jquery'); // — All jQuery modules
window.$ = window.jQuery=jQuery;
require('./jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js'); // works since it searches window.jQuery
```

The final bundle (including my code , minified) was ~164 KB and  most of it was jQuery  , where I didn't need all jQuery's modules !

So I started loading selective modules :

```
var jQuery = require('jquery/src/core');
window.$ = window.jQuery=jQuery;
require('./jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js');
```

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: v.fn.init is not a constructor

Then I've added :

```
var jQuery = require('jquery/src/core');
require('jquery/src/core/init');
window.$ = window.jQuery=jQuery;
require('./jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js');
```

> Different Error: Uncaught TypeError:  _pageWindow.load is not a function

Now I don't know which additional modules I should load.

**Question:**

Which jQuery's (3.1.1) modules should I load ( and in what order) In order for signalR (v2.2.1) to work?

I don't want to load all jQuery's irrelevant functions to my bundle just to make signalr run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a reduced jQuery. As the *README.md* of jQuery's github says, there are some modules can be excluded. I try to find out whether the module can be excluded, and list them below:

- × **ajax**: `$.ajax` is found in signalR.
- × **ajax/xhr**: Generally be with **ajax**.
- × **ajax/script**: Depended by **ajax/jsonp**.
- × **ajax/jsonp**: `jsonp` is found in signalR.
- √ **css**: `css` can't be found in signalR.
- √ **css/showHide**:  The `.show()`, `.hide()` and `.toggle()` and `.css()` can't be found in signalR.
- × **deprecated**: The `.bind()` is found, which is deprecated in jq3.0.
- √ **dimensions**: The `.width()` and `.height()` can't be found.
- √ **effects**: The `.animate()`, `.slideUp()` and `.hide("slow")` can't be found.
- × **event**: The `.on()` is found.
- √ **event/alias**: Seems can be excluded, not sure.
- √ **event/focusin**: No related method can be found.
- × **event/trigger**: The `.triggerHandler()` is found.
- √ **offset**: No related method can be found.
- √ **wrap**: No related method can be found.
- √ **core/ready**: No related method can be found.
- × **deferred**: `.Deferred` is found.
- √ **exports/global**: Handled by you or webpack.
- × **exports/amd**: Should be found by webpack
- √ **sizzle**: Not sure, but probably.

In conclusion, **css**,**css/showHide**,**dimensions**,**effects**,**event/alias**,**event/focusin**,**offset**,**wrap**,**core/ready**,**exports/global** and **sizzle** can be excluded.

Now let's build a reduced jQuery.

1. Download the jquery 3.1.1 zip from [download](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/3.1.1.zip) and enter it
2. `npm i`
3. `npm i -g grunt`
4. `grunt custom:-css,-css/-showHide,-dimensions,-effects,-event/alias,-event/focusin,-offset,-wrap,-core/ready,-exports/global,-sizzle`

Now we get *jquery.js* and *jquery.min.js*(50KB) in dist directory. Copy it to your project and change your code as below:

```
var jQuery = require('./jquery.min.js');
window.$ = window.jQuery=jQuery;
require('./jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js');
```

In case you don't want to build it yourself, I put output files here:(if not available, please build them yourself)

http://blackmiaool.com/res/share/jquery.js

http://blackmiaool.com/res/share/jquery.min.js

If the signalR doesn't work as expected, try the full jQuery instead, and consider including **event/alias** and **sizzle** module.

Comment: In number 4  -  where do you invoke grunt on jQuery ?

Comment: @Royi In the directory uncompressed from the zip in step 1

Comment: @Royi  You forgot to require `jquery/src/deprecated`

Comment: @Royi  Could you give me a test case to verfiy?

Comment: @Royi It's from `jquery/src/manipulation` It seems that you can't just require like that. Some key parts can't be found in the list in my answer. Why not build  it with grunt?